# A question about java web apps and X-REAL-IP header

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I'm setting up a demo of a project for a client. On my server I have a lot of sites built with different technologies that are running under different servers on different ports. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for all of them. This particular application is built with java (spring MVC / Blazeds) and will be deployed under tomcat 6 for the demo (probably in production too). Nginx has a nice setting when used as reverse proxy that enables it to pass the IP address of the original request in the X-REAL-IP header. What I want to do is set up my application or at least tomcat to treat the X-REAL-IP header as the real request IP address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "real request IP". If you're talking about the value returned from `request.getRemoteAddr()` then yes, it's possible.
The way to do that would be to set up a servlet filter in your web application that would intercept all URLs (or only the ones for which you want X-REAL-IP returned) and have that filter wrap incoming request into a descendant of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which will override `getRemoteAddr()` to return X-REAL-IP value.

Comment: It's not technically nessecary to use HttpServletRequestWrapper - you're free to extend whatever, but it is very easy to use.  Yeah, a filter is the answer here - and it's portable to whatever app container you use (as long as the X-REAL-IP header is sent and accepted in that container)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Tomcat's `RemoteIpValve`

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
           remoteIpHeader="X-REAL-IP"
           requestAttributesEnabled="true"
           internalProxies="127.0.0.1"  />
```

That way, when you call `request.getRemoteAddr()`, it will be providing the right information. By the way, you probably want to use the more standard header, which is `X-Forwarded-For`.