# Get client IP address behind load balancer with SSL java

Tags: tomcat, ip, load-balancing

I am having 2 tomcat application servers behind load balancer with ssl. I like to get the IP address from which user request is coming from . I am using this code:

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

`request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` is always null even if property for sending x-forwarded-for is enabled on load balancer, and `request.getRemoteAddr()` is always giving the IP address of load balancer.

When we disable ssl, this work fine, I got client IP, not the IP of the load balancer. Is it possible somehow to get client IP without disabling ssl?

Comment: You need the load balancer to perform the SSL decryption before forwarding, so that it can modify the HTTP header.

Comment: So this mean that nothing can be done in code on server , without changing on the load balancer settings ?

Comment: The proxy can't modify the data in the connection unless it decrypts it first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A question about java web apps and X-REAL-IP header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185627/a-question-about-java-web-apps-and-x-real-ip-header)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I tried below code and it has worked for me

```
private static final String[] HEADERS_LIST = { 
    "X-Forwarded-For",
    "Proxy-Client-IP",
    "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_VIA",
    "REMOTE_ADDR" 
};

public static String getClientIp(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (String header : HEADERS_LIST) {
        String ip = request.getHeader(header);
        if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            return ip;
        }
    }
    return request.getRemoteAddr(); 
}
```

Comment: This does not help me, for all this elements from headers list I got null, I only get value from request.getRemoteAddr(), however I got load balncer IP address, not the address of the actual client request.

Comment: It appears your proxy changes the source IP. When some proxies do that they add the original IP in some custom http header. Use request.getHeaders() and print all of them to see if there isn't anything of interest. Like X-CLIENT-IP

Comment: @HardikSheth That's what his question is about, the X-Forwarded-For header. But if the proxy passes an encrypted connection through without decrypting it, it can't possibly modify the header.