# Where can I find the Apache httpd server IP from within a Tomcat Valve, when AJP was used?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ajp, tomcat-valve

I am working on updating a Tomcat Valve. I want to add a check to see if the caller is coming from localhost/127.0.0.1, which is the case if Apache httpd acts as the frontend webserver on the same machine.
So I added a check for the IP address *request.getRemoteAddr()*.
Unfortunately, this *method* returns the IP address of the client, not of Apache httpd.
The current example code can be [found here](https://github.com/paulklinkenberg/mod_cfml/blob/feature/tomcat-valve-ip-restriction/java/mod_cfml-valve/src/mod_cfml/core.java#L156).

I have been searching through the request objects *[org.apache.coyote.Request](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/Request.html)* and *[org.apache.catalina.connector.Request](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html)*, but could not find any method or Object which would return info about the original AJP call.

So my question is: is it possible to get the IP address of the server who does the AJP call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A question about java web apps and X-REAL-IP header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185627/a-question-about-java-web-apps-and-x-real-ip-header)

Comment: Absolutely not a duplicate. The x-real-ip header is a client IP; I am asking about the server IP.